# By far + comparative

Tags: phrase-usage, comparative

Could someone please let me know whether "by far" can be used comparatively.
Actually, almost all dictionary examples have used it in a superlative comparison, however I'm quite sure I have heard native speakers use it in comparative structures!
Is it a common mistake by native speakers in informal speech or it is something grammatically natural?

Also, it is worth mentioning that I could not find any English grammar rule acknowledging this is wrong to use it in comparative constructions.

**Examples:**

> 1. **Superlative:** It is by far the best car in the world. (Which is perhaps the most common use of the term.)
> 2. **Comparative:** This restaurant is **by far better** than that one.

As a non-native one I cannot find anything wrong with it, but I have no clue why no dictionary has used it in comparative form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two "natural" sequences (most common first) for this "emphatic" comparative usage are...

> 1: *This restaurant is **far better** than that one*  (by far the most common form)
> 2: *This restaurant is **better by far** than that one* (rather "literary" phrasing)

...in this context where *...is **by far better** than that...* is at least "non-idiomatic" (but probably not actually "ungrammatical").

---

Note that ***[by] far*** doesn't directly relate to OP's "superlative / comparative" distinction, which is entirely governed by the choice between ***best*** and ***better***. It's just that the *syntax* of how to use it differs.

Comment: *"...is by far better than that... "*  needs  commas, i.e. "...is, by far, better than that... "

Comment: Only 1 of the first 10 matches for *is by far better than that* in Google Books has commas. But I think the "natural" position for intensifying ***by far*** is AFTER the word ***better***, as per my example #2 above, and the only justification for setting it off by commas is by way of "acknowledging" in the orthography that it's relatively non-idiomatic. [Google Ngrams supports my perspective](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+better+by+far+than%2Cis+by+far+better+than&year_start=1910&year_end=2010&corpus=29&smoothing=3) (more so with BrE, but AmE is broadly similar).